# Twitter Cards using Backbone's HTML5 History

Tags: javascript, web-applications, twitter, backbone.js, html5-history

I'm working on a web app which uses Backbone's HTML5 History option. In order to avoid having to code everything on the client and on the server, I'm using [this method](http://www.josscrowcroft.com/2012/code/htaccess-for-html5-history-pushstate-url-routing/) to route every request to index.html

I was wondering if there is a way to get Twitter Cards to work with this setup, as currently it can't read the page as everything is loaded in dynamically with Javascript.

I was thinking about using User Agents to detect whether it's the TwitterBot, and if it is, serving a static version of the page with the required meta-tags. Would this work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

At one job we did this for all the SEO/search/facebook stuff etc.

We would sniff the user-agent, and if it was one of the following sniffers

- Facebook Open Graph
- Google
- Bing
- Twitter
- Yandex
- (a few others I can't remember)

we would redirect to a special page that was written to dump all the relevant data about the page for SEO purposes into a nicely formatted (but completely unstyled) page.

This allowed us to retain our google index position and proper facebook sharing even though our site was a total single-page app in backbone.

Comment: Only thing I'm worried about is I might get my sight blacklisted on Google for trying to "fool" them...

Comment: As long as the page has all the data on it that would be present when a user would load it in the browser, it shouldn't be an issue.  Our page included the images, links, etc, just in an unstyled html page.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, serving a specific page for Twitterbot with the right meta data markup will work.

You can test your results while developing using the card's preview tool.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/cards/preview (with your static URL or just the tags).